# Count values in another sheet in Google Spreadsheet where sheet name is a cell value using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I cannot share a sample because this is G-Suite Enterprise and it is locked. If absolutely needed I can create a dummy one on my personal Gmail.

One of the sheets has a list of lookup values and sheet names. I am trying to come up with an `ARRAYFORMULA` that will count the # of times `Lookup Value` shows in column A of `Lookup Sheet Name`.

```
| Lookup Value | Lookup Sheet Name | Count |
|--------------|-------------------|-------|
| one          | Primary           | ...   |
| two          | Secondary         | ...   |
| three        | Stuff             | ...   |
| ...          | Primary           | ...   |
| ...          | ...               | ...   |
```

I came up with this formula For `C2` but it does not work. I don't exactly know why but it shows `1` for every lookup value or just one row with `1`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A <> "", COUNTIF(INDIRECT(B2:B & "!A2:A"), A2:A), ))
```

I **do not** want to use Google Apps Script to solve this.

Comment: I can't find a solution for this problem as the `INDIRECT` is not looped with the ArrayFormula (it will always keep the value of the first cell) and the `INDIRECT` is absolutely necessary in your problem, hope you or someone else finds a solution to it and will bookmark to see if someone came up with a solution to it

Comment: Yeah -- I figured as much. But I thought I would try posting JIC someone has a clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that combines the values of the different sheets in one by adding a second column with constant value (the name of the seet for example).

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(A:A<>"",
    COUNTIFS(
      {
        FILTER('sheet A'!A:A,NOT(ISBLANK('sheet A'!A:A)));
        FILTER('sheet B'!A:A,NOT(ISBLANK('sheet B'!A:A)))
      },"="&A:A,
      {
        FILTER(IF(ISBLANK('sheet A'!A:A),,"sheet A"),NOT(ISBLANK('sheet A'!A:A)));
        FILTER(IF(ISBLANK('sheet B'!A:A),,"sheet B"),NOT(ISBLANK('sheet B'!A:A)))
      },"="&B:B
    ),
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: This could work but I'll have an arbitrary number of sheets. :/

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan In this case, you can create a script that is triggered when a sheet is created/deleted, and that modifies this formula by listing all available sheets.

Comment: Yeah -- hoping to avoid any scripting for this. I'll keep looking and if I can't find something then I'll use a script.